# WPF - create ProgressBar template from PSD file

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm starting my adventure with WPF and after creating my first application I want to style it a bit. I found [UI template](http://graphicburger.com/mobile-game-gui/) and using Blend for VS2013 I imported PSD into my project.

Here is how ProgressBar looks in PSD:
[image]

and here is what it looks when imported to Blend:
[image]

And here is code:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="Progress1" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="493" Margin="0,307.5,0,-53.5">
        <Canvas x:Name="Loading" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493">
            <Path x:Name="Base2" Data="F1M22.086,3C22.086,3 63.118,4.562 125.833,3 199.069,1.175 294.072,5.645 370.146,4.333 430.323,3.294 474,3 474,3 479.523,3 487.826,8.208 489.687,15.098 491.864,23.156 491.191,28.867 489.081,37.118 487.415,43.637 479.856,47.999 474.333,47.999 474.333,47.999 368.324,50.176 252.792,47.999 135.568,45.792 42.104,49.541 23.518,47.999 12.306,47.07 6.028,45.811 4.028,37.787 3.199,34.461 1.441,23.222 7.178,11.906 10.179,5.987 16.563,3 22.086,3z" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC18A13" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9A0C" Offset="0.339"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Stroke>
                <Path.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE4882D" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF5CA09" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
            <Path x:Name="Bg" Data="F1M16.361,2.603C16.361,2.603 133.014,3.416 247.396,3.478 311.817,3.513 376.242,2.615 416.922,1.936 446.114,1.448 458.772,2.411 458.772,2.411 462.592,2.411 469.449,4.823 471.077,9.484 473.896,17.557 472.201,20.776 471.202,25.468 470.232,30.02 467.977,31.719 459.43,33.25 450.883,34.782 424.628,32.594 376,32.594 298.703,32.594 184.467,31.065 105.75,30.911 54.767,30.812 18.683,32.063 17.185,32.063 9.403,32.063 6.954,28.298 5.436,25.402 4.335,23.303 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 12.541,2.603 16.361,2.603z" Fill="#FFA77235" Height="36" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="8" Width="475"/>
            <Path x:Name="Progress" Data="F1M19.986,2.29C19.986,2.29 50.058,4.582 104.021,2.936 154.279,1.403 214.797,4.02 264,4.02 310.844,4.02 341.117,2.457 347.659,2.936 354.201,3.415 356.173,5.804 357.743,10.484 359.313,15.162 360.055,20.568 357.202,26.468 355.175,30.658 353.597,31.417 347.492,33.396 345.484,34.047 309.622,34.937 262.208,34.943 217.536,34.948 162.63,33.886 116.105,33.683 61.905,33.446 19.087,34.063 17.185,34.063 9.403,34.063 6.016,31.048 4.498,28.152 3.397,26.053 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 16.166,2.29 19.986,2.29z" Height="36" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="7" Width="362">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF4E" Offset="0.409"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF159308" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

My problem is how can I convert that canvas to ProgressBar Template.

Based on tutorial I was able to create template, but there were rectangles not paths. I've tried using paths but I can't align them correctly.

How can I create Template that uses Path as PART_Track and PART_Indicator and how can I add text to that ProgressBar?

I imagine this as 3 layers: component background (orange one), progress background (brown) and progress bar (green).
Maybe I should use two layers: progress bar and background with stroke?

This is my first template so I'd like to do it best I can.

I couldn't find similar question on SO (except [snail progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749527/how-to-use-psd-in-wpf-progressbar), but there solution is based on images instead of paths).

Comment: I've seen about 3 questions exactly the same as this in the last month..

Comment: @GlenThomas could You please post link to them? I'm always thying to find solutions before asking new question

Comment: I can't find them now... Although you have constructed something that looks like a progress bar, it is static and making the fill path change according to the progress value will be extremely difficult. You would be better off starting with the default control template for a progress bar and adjusting it to look how you want.

Comment: @GlenThomas as I wrote in my question I`d like to start with something. Solution that uses attached image would be greate, but a generic example how to use path in progressbar template would also be helpfull :-)

Comment: The problem is the nature of a Path. Its shape is fairly static unless you go changing the points data, which will be extremely difficult. Could you replace your Path with a Rectangle control with a CornerRadius? It could have exactly the same appearance as your Path, but would adjust its width much easier.

Comment: @GlenThomas I'd like to add irregular shape to progressbar, so rectangle isn't an option. Or maybe I can get that effect (see first image in my question) without using path?

Comment: I think you can use clipping to achieve that effect, but I am no expert on that particular area. I would suggest you try to create the progress bar using a rectangle or similar control for the track and ask another question if you get stuck, as this is very difficult using a Path

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an idea about how you could make working progress bar from that template.

First, we create custom wpf control and inherit from ProgressBar:

```
public class MyProgressBar : ProgressBar {
    static MyProgressBar() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (MyProgressBar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (MyProgressBar)));
    }
}
```

Then we go in Themes/Generic.xaml file (which was created for us by Visual Studio if was not present) and create look of our control:

```
<local:MyProgressBarWidthConverter x:Key="width" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyProgressBar}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
                        <Canvas x:Name="Progress1" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="493">
                            <Canvas x:Name="Loading" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493">
                                <Path x:Name="Base2" Data="F1M22.086,3C22.086,3 63.118,4.562 125.833,3 199.069,1.175 294.072,5.645 370.146,4.333 430.323,3.294 474,3 474,3 479.523,3 487.826,8.208 489.687,15.098 491.864,23.156 491.191,28.867 489.081,37.118 487.415,43.637 479.856,47.999 474.333,47.999 474.333,47.999 368.324,50.176 252.792,47.999 135.568,45.792 42.104,49.541 23.518,47.999 12.306,47.07 6.028,45.811 4.028,37.787 3.199,34.461 1.441,23.222 7.178,11.906 10.179,5.987 16.563,3 22.086,3z" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493" StrokeThickness="2">
                                    <Path.Stroke>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC18A13" Offset="1"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9A0C" Offset="0.339"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Path.Stroke>
                                    <Path.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFE4882D" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF5CA09" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Path.Fill>
                                </Path>
                                <Path x:Name="Bg" Data="F1M16.361,2.603C16.361,2.603 133.014,3.416 247.396,3.478 311.817,3.513 376.242,2.615 416.922,1.936 446.114,1.448 458.772,2.411 458.772,2.411 462.592,2.411 469.449,4.823 471.077,9.484 473.896,17.557 472.201,20.776 471.202,25.468 470.232,30.02 467.977,31.719 459.43,33.25 450.883,34.782 424.628,32.594 376,32.594 298.703,32.594 184.467,31.065 105.75,30.911 54.767,30.812 18.683,32.063 17.185,32.063 9.403,32.063 6.954,28.298 5.436,25.402 4.335,23.303 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 12.541,2.603 16.361,2.603z" Fill="#FFA77235" Height="36" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="8" Width="475"/>
                                <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="7" Height="36">
                                    <Viewbox.Width>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource width}">
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum" />
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value" />
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Viewbox.Width>
                                    <Path x:Name="Progress" Data="F1M19.986,2.29C19.986,2.29 50.058,4.582 104.021,2.936 154.279,1.403 214.797,4.02 264,4.02 310.844,4.02 341.117,2.457 347.659,2.936 354.201,3.415 356.173,5.804 357.743,10.484 359.313,15.162 360.055,20.568 357.202,26.468 355.175,30.658 353.597,31.417 347.492,33.396 345.484,34.047 309.622,34.937 262.208,34.943 217.536,34.948 162.63,33.886 116.105,33.683 61.905,33.446 19.087,34.063 17.185,34.063 9.403,34.063 6.016,31.048 4.498,28.152 3.397,26.053 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 16.166,2.29 19.986,2.29z" >
                                        <Path.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF4E" Offset="0.409"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF159308" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Path.Fill>
                                    </Path>
                                </Viewbox>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Basically we just put entire canvas from your psd inside Viewbox with Stretch=Fill (and also removed unnecessary margins). Note that all sizes are the same and hardcoded, but because we put control inside viewbox, it will stretch to the dimensions of viewbox. And because that is viewbox with Stretch=Fill and without specified width and height - it will stretch to the size of control. We also put Path which corresponds to green fill to it's own viewbox, because we will need to resize that Path according to ProgressBar.Value parameter.

Now we create converter for green Path's viewbox Width:

```
 public class MyProgressBarWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (values.Any(c => c == null || c == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return 0.0d;
        var min = (double) values[0];
        var current = (double) values[1];
        var max = (double) values[2];
        const double maxWidth = 475; // that is from template
        return (current/(max - min))*maxWidth;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There we pass Minimum, Value, Maximum of progress bar and calculate green bar width. Maximum available width is always 475, but remember we put that in viewbox, so our control is *not* fixed to 475 width.

Then we put control in window:

```
 <wpf:MyProgressBar x:Name="bar" Width="500" Height="50" Value="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer()
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };
        timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (bar.Value < bar.Maximum)
                bar.Value++;
            else
                timer.Stop();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

And watching how our progressbar works. 
In general, if you have heavy UI, you might want to work with simple forms, because many paths inside viewboxes are not very efficient. But if you *have* to work with fixed paths from PSD... Why not.

EDIT to answer your comment. Sure it's not required to create new control, it's just more flexible. If you don't want to do this, just create control template for your progress bar and assign to existing ProgressBar.ControlTemplate, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <wpf:MyProgressBarWidthConverter x:Key="width" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="myProgressBar" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
                <Canvas x:Name="Progress1" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="493">
                    <Canvas x:Name="Loading" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493">
                        <Path x:Name="Base2" Data="F1M22.086,3C22.086,3 63.118,4.562 125.833,3 199.069,1.175 294.072,5.645 370.146,4.333 430.323,3.294 474,3 474,3 479.523,3 487.826,8.208 489.687,15.098 491.864,23.156 491.191,28.867 489.081,37.118 487.415,43.637 479.856,47.999 474.333,47.999 474.333,47.999 368.324,50.176 252.792,47.999 135.568,45.792 42.104,49.541 23.518,47.999 12.306,47.07 6.028,45.811 4.028,37.787 3.199,34.461 1.441,23.222 7.178,11.906 10.179,5.987 16.563,3 22.086,3z" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493" StrokeThickness="2">
                            <Path.Stroke>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC18A13" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9A0C" Offset="0.339"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Stroke>
                            <Path.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE4882D" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF5CA09" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Path.Fill>
                        </Path>
                        <Path x:Name="Bg" Data="F1M16.361,2.603C16.361,2.603 133.014,3.416 247.396,3.478 311.817,3.513 376.242,2.615 416.922,1.936 446.114,1.448 458.772,2.411 458.772,2.411 462.592,2.411 469.449,4.823 471.077,9.484 473.896,17.557 472.201,20.776 471.202,25.468 470.232,30.02 467.977,31.719 459.43,33.25 450.883,34.782 424.628,32.594 376,32.594 298.703,32.594 184.467,31.065 105.75,30.911 54.767,30.812 18.683,32.063 17.185,32.063 9.403,32.063 6.954,28.298 5.436,25.402 4.335,23.303 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 12.541,2.603 16.361,2.603z" Fill="#FFA77235" Height="36" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="8" Width="475"/>
                        <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="7" Height="36">
                            <Viewbox.Width>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource width}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum" />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value" />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Viewbox.Width>
                            <Path x:Name="Progress" Data="F1M19.986,2.29C19.986,2.29 50.058,4.582 104.021,2.936 154.279,1.403 214.797,4.02 264,4.02 310.844,4.02 341.117,2.457 347.659,2.936 354.201,3.415 356.173,5.804 357.743,10.484 359.313,15.162 360.055,20.568 357.202,26.468 355.175,30.658 353.597,31.417 347.492,33.396 345.484,34.047 309.622,34.937 262.208,34.943 217.536,34.948 162.63,33.886 116.105,33.683 61.905,33.446 19.087,34.063 17.185,34.063 9.403,34.063 6.016,31.048 4.498,28.152 3.397,26.053 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 16.166,2.29 19.986,2.29z" >
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF4E" Offset="0.409"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF159308" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Canvas>
                </Canvas>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ProgressBar x:Name="bar" Width="500" Height="50" Value="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Template="{StaticResource myProgressBar}"/>
```

Comment: thank You for that. This is something I was looking for. Before I posted my question I was trying to create template for ProgressBar, not custom control. Would it be hard to create template (skin) for ProgressBar instead creating new control? Sorry for newbie question but I'm quite new to WPF (I worked with WinForms before) and this stuff is all new to me.

Comment: I checked Your style just minute ago, sorry for delay. Style looks fine for higher values, but for lower it's just ugly. Could You help me fix this?

Comment: @Misiu sure, check updated code. Just change inner (or both) ViewBoxes Stretch property from Fill to UniformToFill.

Comment: I've did that, but now with larger values green bar gets re-sized vertically

Comment: @Misiu Try setting outer ViewBox.Stretch to Fill, and inner ViewBox.Stretch to UniformToFill. With this don't see any problems on lower or larger values.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a protoype of how your control template can be.

Firstly I have created a IMultiValueConverter defined as followed:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class RatioConveter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]) * System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1])) / System.Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then I declared it as a resource in the wpf window (I omissis the declaration of the namespace):

```
<yourNamespace:RatioConveter x:Key="ratioConverter" />
```

Then I prepared a `Style` which applies the control template to all the `ProgressBar` in the window defined in this way:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}"
           TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Container"  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">                            
                        <Canvas x:Name="Progress1" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Width="493" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" >
                            <Canvas.Resources>
                                <system:Double x:Key="ratioConstant">1</system:Double>
                            </Canvas.Resources>
                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0"
                                                CenterY="0">
                                    <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ratioConverter}">
                                            <Binding ElementName="Container" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource ratioConstant}"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="Progress1" Path="Width"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                    <ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ratioConverter}">
                                            <Binding ElementName="Container" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource ratioConstant}"/>
                                            <Binding ElementName="Progress1" Path="Height"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
                                </ScaleTransform>
                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                            <Path x:Name="Base2" Data="F1M22.086,3C22.086,3 63.118,4.562 125.833,3 199.069,1.175 294.072,5.645 370.146,4.333 430.323,3.294 474,3 474,3 479.523,3 487.826,8.208 489.687,15.098 491.864,23.156 491.191,28.867 489.081,37.118 487.415,43.637 479.856,47.999 474.333,47.999 474.333,47.999 368.324,50.176 252.792,47.999 135.568,45.792 42.104,49.541 23.518,47.999 12.306,47.07 6.028,45.811 4.028,37.787 3.199,34.461 1.441,23.222 7.178,11.906 10.179,5.987 16.563,3 22.086,3z" Height="52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="493" StrokeThickness="2">
                                <Path.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC18A13" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9A0C" Offset="0.339"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Stroke>
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE4882D" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF5CA09" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                            <Path x:Name="Bg" Data="F1M16.361,2.603C16.361,2.603 133.014,3.416 247.396,3.478 311.817,3.513 376.242,2.615 416.922,1.936 446.114,1.448 458.772,2.411 458.772,2.411 462.592,2.411 469.449,4.823 471.077,9.484 473.896,17.557 472.201,20.776 471.202,25.468 470.232,30.02 467.977,31.719 459.43,33.25 450.883,34.782 424.628,32.594 376,32.594 298.703,32.594 184.467,31.065 105.75,30.911 54.767,30.812 18.683,32.063 17.185,32.063 9.403,32.063 6.954,28.298 5.436,25.402 4.335,23.303 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 12.541,2.603 16.361,2.603z" Fill="#FFA77235" Height="36" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="8" Width="475"/>
                            <Path x:Name="Progress" Data="F1M19.986,2.29C19.986,2.29 50.058,4.582 104.021,2.936 154.279,1.403 214.797,4.02 264,4.02 310.844,4.02 341.117,2.457 347.659,2.936 354.201,3.415 356.173,5.804 357.743,10.484 359.313,15.162 360.055,20.568 357.202,26.468 355.175,30.658 353.597,31.417 347.492,33.396 345.484,34.047 309.622,34.937 262.208,34.943 217.536,34.948 162.63,33.886 116.105,33.683 61.905,33.446 19.087,34.063 17.185,34.063 9.403,34.063 6.016,31.048 4.498,28.152 3.397,26.053 1.86,15.809 6.797,8.253 9.308,4.41 16.166,2.29 19.986,2.29z" Height="36" Canvas.Left="8" Canvas.Top="7" Width="362">
                                <Path.Resources>
                                    <system:Double x:Key="ratioConstant">27500</system:Double>
                                </Path.Resources>
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0"
                                                CenterY="0">
                                        <ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ratioConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="Progress" Path="Width"/>
                                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource ratioConstant}"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </ScaleTransform.ScaleX>
                                    </ScaleTransform>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                <Path.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF4E" Offset="0.409"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF159308" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Fill>
                            </Path>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1"
                                     StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlDarkColor}"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Note: The code may need some improvements but at least is a good start, the graphics when you reach low values in the progress bar doesn't seem to be very beautiful but surely you can improve the graphic of the control based in your needings.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank You for help. Any ideas how this can be fixed for low values? @kyle style looks better with low values, but I'd like to get that irregular shape look.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I was thinking about another solution to show the "curvy" bar without using code, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified you code at my end and crafted out a working solution.

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC18A13" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9A0C" Offset="0.339"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE4882D" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF5CA09" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF5DFF4E" Offset="0.409"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF159308" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">

                    <Grid MinHeight="24" MinWidth="100">



                        <Border Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="15" Background="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"  BorderThickness="10">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Grid>

                                            <Path x:Name="path1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Fill="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Data="F1M22.086,3C22.086,3 63.118,4.562 125.833,3 199.069,1.175 294.072,5.645 370.146,4.333 430.323,3.294 474,3 474,3 479.523,3 487.826,8.208 489.687,15.098 491.864,23.156 491.191,28.867 489.081,37.118 487.415,43.637 479.856,47.999 474.333,47.999 474.333,47.999 368.324,50.176 252.792,47.999 135.568,45.792 42.104,49.541 23.518,47.999 12.306,47.07 6.028,45.811 4.028,37.787 3.199,34.461 1.441,23.222 7.178,11.906 10.179,5.987 16.563,3 22.086,3z"></Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Name="PART_Indicator"  CornerRadius="15" Background="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="10">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <VisualBrush>
                                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Path x:Name="path" Stretch="Fill"  Fill="Transparent" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Data="F1M22.086,3C22.086,3 63.118,4.562 125.833,3 199.069,1.175 294.072,5.645 370.146,4.333 430.323,3.294 474,3 474,3 479.523,3 487.826,8.208 489.687,15.098 491.864,23.156 491.191,28.867 489.081,37.118 487.415,43.637 479.856,47.999 474.333,47.999 474.333,47.999 368.324,50.176 252.792,47.999 135.568,45.792 42.104,49.541 23.518,47.999 12.306,47.07 6.028,45.811 4.028,37.787 3.199,34.461 1.441,23.222 7.178,11.906 10.179,5.987 16.563,3 22.086,3z"></Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                </VisualBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Just to complete this example

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="100">
    <ProgressBar Height="61" Value="20" x:Name="sampleProgressBar"  />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ElementName=sampleProgressBar,Path=Value}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now you can set the progress bar and its value will be reflected on the TextBlock. You can also customize the textblock style to get your desired effect.

Comment: I'll check that right after I get back home. I know that shape of progressbar is irregular, but as I see in Your answer same effect can be done with border instead of paths. I'll write back after I check that.